# Small signal equivalent circuit of multistage amplifier

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, bjt, fet

I've been trying to draw the small signal equivalent circuit of this circuit and derive the expression for voltage.
Using the equivalent circuit I drew, I derived the voltage gain expression but I got something different from the material. I'm not sure if my equivalent circuit is correct and would require assistance.

multistage amplifier and equivalent circuit:

[image: Image showing multistage amplifier and equivalent circuit i drew]

Comment: Everything looks good except the VSCS (gm*Vsg) direction. The arrow should point to GND (down).

Comment: Alright... And there are no missing resistors too?

Comment: All resistors that should be present on the diagram are already there. So maybe you should show us your calculation so that we can check if there is a any error in your calculations.